# Iterate through dictionary to get a list of values

Tags: python

I want to make a list out of the nested dictionary:

```
{'Name': {'20': 'Paul Merrill', '21': 'Brynne S. Barr', }, 
'Phone': {'20': '1-313-739-3854', '21': '939-4818', }, 
'Address': {'20': '916-8087 Vehicula Rd.', '21': '878-2231 Suspendisse Rd.', },
'City': {'20': 'Le Mans', '21': 'Wilhelmshaven',}
```

to a list with key as the identifier, so it will be something like this:

```
['20', 'Paul Merril', '1-313-739-3854', '916-8087 Vehicula Rd.', 'Le Mans']
['21', 'Paul Merril', '939-4818', '878-2231 Suspendisse Rd.', 'Wilhelmshave']
```

and so on...(i have like 50 entries, for simplification, i just put two here)

I have tried to get a single entry use:

```
 L = [v.get('20') for v in table_2.values()]
```

but just not sure how to iterate through the keys (21, 22, 23, 24...) until the list is over?
the following code gives me [None, None, None, None, None, None]

```
for i in table_2:
    L = [v.get('i') for v in table_2.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table_2 = {'Name': {'20': 'Paul Merrill', '21': 'Brynne S. Barr', },
'Phone': {'20': '1-313-739-3854', '21': '939-4818', },
'Address': {'20': '916-8087 Vehicula Rd.', '21': '878-2231 Suspendisse Rd.', },
'City': {'20': 'Le Mans', '21': 'Wilhelmshaven',}}

# you can get the list of keys to get the values

values_list = []
key_list = [v.keys() for v in table_2.values()]
keylist = []

for key in key_list:
    keylist = list(key)


for i in keylist:
    values_list.append([i, table_2.get('Name').get(i), table_2.get('Phone').get(i),
                        table_2.get('Address').get(i), table_2.get('City').get(i)])

print(values_list)
```